# Polymer - Get data-bound attribute value in repeating template

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm having a bit of an issue here. I had a small amount of success with `event.target.templateInstance.model.thing` syntax to get the value of attributes from within a repeating template but I keep getting back `undefined` from this bit of code I have here:

```
downloadFunction: function (e) {
  console.log("dl function clicked");
  //get particular id of thing
  var fu = e.target.templateInstance.model.s.soundId;
  console.log(fu);
  //^ returns "TypeError: Cannot read property 'soundId' of undefined"
}
```

And my repeating template is here:

```
<div layout horizontal wrap center center-justified>
  <template repeat="{{s in carddata}}">
    <sound-card image="{{s.imgurl}}"
                quotetext="{{s.quote}}"
                soundsrc="{{s.soundurl}}"
                soundref="{{s.soundId}}"
                downloadfunction="{{downloadFunction}}">
    </sound-card>
  </template>
</div>
```

Where `carddata` is just an array with my data in it. All of the values are generated fine so I know it's not an issue with my array. I'm just confused how exactly I'm supposed to target someting from within the repeating template? Am I calling it at the wrong time? Or am I messing up the syntax of the `templateInstance` bit?

If it matters, I'm trying to get it to work in an Android 4.4 webView using Apache Cordova. 4.4 webView doesn't appear to enjoy the shadowDOM terribly much.

Thanks!

**edit:** After some jiggery pokery with console logs, it appears that the `sender` value is referring to the div that I apply the `on-click="{{downloadFunction}}` to. Here's the template that I am repeating, if this provides any insight.

```
<div class="soundcard-container" vertical layout>
  //can't target this one either on WebView 4.4, works on ChromeOS
  <img src="{{image}}" on-tap="{{playAudio}}">
  <div class="soundcard-bottom-container" horizontal layout center justified>
  <span>{{quotetext}}</span>
  //I have an 'a' tag for desktop browsers and the div tag is targeting my Android/iOS
  //apps that I am exporting as a webView to using Apache Cordova. Webonly is hidden
  //at the point where I'm trying to get my downloadfunction to work.
  <a href="{{soundsrc}}" download="{{quotetext}}.m4a" class="webonly"></a>
  //console.log(sender) in my downloadfunction returns this div v
  <div on-tap="{{downloadfunction}}" class="mobileonly"></div>
</div>
//just a hidden audio thing for web
<div style="display: none">
  <audio id="{{soundref}}" src="{{soundsrc}}" controls preload="auto"></audio>
</div>
    </div>
```

**edit2** some console logs..

`console.log(sender)` and `console.log(event.target)` are both the same div that has the on-click event for my `downloadFunction`.. not sure if this should be the case.

`console.log(e.target.templateInstance.model)` returns my `<sound-card>` object, I believe like it should(?)

It's just when I add the specific `.s.soundId` that it's undefined. I'm not sure why it's unable to find it.. Maybe there's another way to get the specific soundId (or s.soundId rather) of that particular `<sound-card>` object?

Answer (score 0):

Here is working example of using templateInstance, with included selecting by dynamic ID: [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/wu3gVIAwZfW4KmSNraTF?p=preview) .
 As for your code,  can't tell why it's not working.

```
handleEvent: function(e, detail, sender) {

  console.log('handleEvent');
  console.log(sender.id);

  //How to catch full_obj here, 
  //..as if first item is clicked:  full_obj = {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}
  //console.log(e);
  console.log(e.target.templateInstance.model.item.firstName);
  //console.log(detail);
  //console.log(sender);

  this.instance_firstName = e.target.templateInstance.model.item.firstName;
  this.instance_lastName  = e.target.templateInstance.model.item.lastName;


  //Selecting by dynamic ID
  var clicked_element = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#'+this.instance_firstName);
  console.log('Selecting');
  console.log(clicked_element);
  //var second_element = sender.templateInstance.model.querySelector('my-second-element');
  //var second_element = this.$.second_element;
}
```

Edit:
[Event handling and data binding Docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/databinding.html#event-handling-and-data-binding)

Comment: Yeah this is what I'm doing also. Not working for me :-/

Answer (score 0):

I'll bet you want to refer to the "sender" of the event—not `e.target`. See the part about `inSender` at https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/polymer.html#declarative-event-mapping:

> `inSender`: A reference to the node that declared the handler. This is
>   often different from inEvent.target (the lowest node that received the
>   event) and inEvent.currentTarget (the component processing the event),
>   so Polymer provides it directly.

This might fix it:

```
downloadFunction: function (e, detail, sender) {
  console.log("dl function clicked");
  //get particular id of thing
  var fu = sender.templateInstance.model.s.soundId;
  console.log(fu);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the documentation! Unfortunately it still says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'soundId' of undefined". Hmm..

Comment: Here I'm going to update my code with some more information from console logging, one second

Comment: Looks like event.target and sender are both returning the same value, the div that the event is called from.. Is this supposed to be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Alright I was able to fit this in a different way. I wasn't able to get `e.target.templateInstance.model.s.soundId` bit to work, so instead on the div that I call the event on (`event.target`) I gave it an attribute called `data-soundid` and passed it `{{soundref}}` from my original template and then where I repeat that template I simply made a function like so:

```
downloady: function (e) {
  console.log(e.target.getAttribute('data-soundurl'));
}
```

Ta da! Very nice solution. Thanks to [Eyal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4013403/eyal) who suggested this to me in a previous question. It works like a charm. :-)